# Get and return filepath by foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, directory

I want to make a program to able to save every file path which the user selected.
after that do some prosses for each file. for example, convert video file one by one.
Could you tell me why `foreach` does not work?

```
        private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialogInput = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialogInput.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        openFileDialogInput.Filter = "Video Files|*.mp4|TS Files|*.ts";
        openFileDialogInput.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialogInput.FilterIndex = 1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialogInput.ShowDialog();
        string [] inputPath = openFileDialogInput.FileNames;

        foreach (var item in inputPath)
        {
            item;
        }
    }
```

inputPath gets all file paths that the user selected. but I don't know how can I get them, one by one and make some prosses on them.

Comment: inside the foreach, "item;" is syntax error. What would you like to process with the item?

Comment: add watermark on each video file(mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try this:

```
private void AddWatermark(string videoFilePath)
{
    // Add your logic here to add watermark
}
```

And in the foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in inputPath)
{
   AddWatermark(item);
}
```